# Create Granite model from JSON params

Tags: crystal-lang, kemal

What I would like to have happen: Someone can make a post request to `users/new` with parameters, and I would like to create a `User` object from the JSON parameters.

In the readme, it gives this example:

```
foo = Foo.from_json(%({"name": "Granite1"}))
```

But when I try to do this I get this compile-time error:

```
in /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.26.1/src/json/pull_parser.cr:13: no 
overload matches 'JSON::Lexer.new' with type Hash(String, Array(JSON::Any) | Bool | Float64 | Hash(String, JSON::Any) | Int64 | String | Nil)

Overloads are:
- JSON::Lexer.new(string : String)
- JSON::Lexer.new(io : IO)
- JSON::Lexer.new()

@lexer = Lexer.new input
               ^~~
```

Here is what `env.params.json` looks like when logged to the console:

```
{"name" => "test",
 "username" => "tester",
 "email" => "test",
 "password" => "test"}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is steering you in the right direction here. It looks like you're passing in a variable that, at compile-time, has the type `Hash(String, V)` where `V` is one of the types

- `Array(JSON::Any)`
- `Bool`
- `Float64`
- `Hash(String, JSON::Any)`
- `Int64`
- `String`
- `Nil`

What it's *expecting* is a `String` (or an `IO` object, which is similar to a `String`) of JSON. That's what you have in the example. `%(foo)` is another way to create the `String` `"foo"` (See ["Percent string literals"](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/literals/string.html) in the guide for more info). They're using it here because it allows you to avoid escaping the double quotes used in the JSON.

Based on the compile-time type that Crystal has given your parameter, my guess is that it's already been converted from JSON into a Crystal `Hash`. Double-check that you're not parsing it twice.

Without seeing the source, there's not much more information I can provide, but I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I haven't had time to work on that project in a little while. Once I do, if your solution works, I'll accept it as the answer.